# Magento2 - Override theme phtml

Tags: magento2, theme

How override a default phtml in Magento 2?

I want to update/improve the theme "magento_plushe".
I add a file on `app\design\frontend\magento_plushe\Magento_Theme\html\header.phtml`
But Magento ignore this file and load `app\code\Magento\Page\view\frontend\html\header.phtml`

Configuration: 
-Magento 2.0.0.0-dev55
-Cache disabled

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a pre-alpha version of Magento 2 and no longer relevant

Comment: Please refer to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101501/override-magento-2-phtml-files/101502#101502 **if you are looking for a solution for Magento 2.0**

Answer (score 2):

works in 2.0.0.0-dev57 as you tried.

But: if you want to create an improved design, you should create an own theme which extends from magento_plushe.

Comment: I found the problem. In var/maps/fallback Magento 2 keep the default path for the header.phtml. If I clean this folder fallback, Magento regenerate new correct path for header.phtml. Clear the cache in adminhtml don't clean the maps/fallback folder...

Comment: Problem is, this is not really a cache.
Magento will soon introduce so called deployment scripts, which do a lot of stuff.
This is one of the parts the deployment scripts will cover.

Answer (score 0):

The correct path to override a base template file in your case would be
/app/design/frontend/PackageName/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/**templates**/html/header.phtml

But, be careful when overriding base template files. Only do it when you can't do it with XML/CSS. It's always better to avoid this to have an easier upgrade path when Magento 2.x is updated.