# Override Magento 2 phtml Files?

Tags: magento2, phtml

Is it possible to override Magento 2 Luma phtml Files? I've created a new theme based on Luma which is working perfectly but I can't find any phtml files anywhere.

I've also noticed my app/code directory is completely empty.

Comment: You may be download  code from magento site instead of github thus you can  not see app/code.You see all module at  vendor/magento folder ... It  composer already implement this code base.  If want to custom theme then create app/code  and implement whatever yiu want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can find luma theme files are located

copy from here

`vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma`

add in your theme

`app/design/frontend/spacename/theme/`

you are missing `templates` in path `/app/design/frontend/Penguin/default/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml`

Comment: Didn't work for me. I still can't get the header.phtml file to work, without editing the "vendor" version.

Comment: did you set your theme in admin?

Comment: Sure did! And cleared the cache in both the back end and the browser.

Comment: did you deploy the content.  `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy  en_US`

Comment: Yeah I did. The theme is showing as active in the back end but when displaying the active blocks using the developer hinting options it's still getting all phtml files from vendor. The css and images are the only items that are correctly being pulled from my custom theme (copy of Luma renamed).

Comment: can you add one phtml file path? here so i can check there is not problem in path.

Comment: The file path is `/app/design/frontend/Penguin/default/Magento_Theme/html/header.phtml` - I also created a module which is active but doesn't pull in the file `app/code/Atomic/Penguin/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml`. I just want to easily be able edit some of the vendor phtml files, without editing vendor itself (I'm assuming I'm not supposed to edit vendor files).

Comment: you are missing templates in path 
`/app/design/frontend/Penguin/default/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml` this will be your file path

Answer (score 3):

`App/code` empty is ok if you installed via Composer!

In your `app/design/frontend/Magento/luma` folder you can find all your modules that are customized either from `app/design/frontend/Magento/luma` or the core modules `app/code/Magento/`

For catalog list phtml you can for example copy the files from
`app/code/Magento/catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` into your custom `app/design/frontend/<yourvendorfolder>/<yourthemefolder>/Magento_Catalog/templates/html/list.phtml`

here you go, think you should run through the devdocs some more to get to know the logic behind the magento2 file and override structure.
its not like Magento1 just copy over few templates files and done. 85% is done via layout xml files and just small bits via phtml.

Good luck!

Comment: app/code being empty is perfectly fine if you have installed magento using composer. Everything will live in the vendor/ directory instead.

Comment: pls check following path vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma

Comment: I can't find any .phtml files inside vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma either!

Comment: i just copy template from `vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma` to design in app but after clear cache theme not apply new template